# Windows 8 Fails to resume from sleep

Tags: windows-8, laptop, sleep

I have this weird issue. When I put the computer to sleep by pressing the power button, or using the sleep option in Charms, I can wake it up normally. However, if I close the lid, and later reopen it, all the fans come on, but **nothing** appears on the screen.

I didn't have this issue using Windows 7.

Here are my system specs:

> HP G60-235DX Notebook PC
>
> Intel Pentium Dual Core T4200 at 2.00Ghz
>
> 3 GBS of RAM
>
> Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 4500MHD with 1309MB of video memory
>
> Windows 8 Pro 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues and the problem was the graphic driver. Check your drivers and update them, this might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it didn't work for me. I tried updating it via Windows Update, Device Manager, and the HP website. Unfortunately, all of them reported that the driver was up to date.

Answer (score 0):

- Check settings in power configuration what does closing the lid do it might be hibernating try setting closing lid event to sleep

Link: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9090/learning-windows-7-manage-power-settings/

Comment: I already checked, it's set to sleep. Also, if it was set to hibernate, then when I open the lid, nothing should have happened.

Comment: Locate manufacture website and download the display, chipset drivers if you cant find it for win8 then go to www.pcidatabase.com and locate Device id in device manager.